# Dart parse full dateTime including am/pm

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my date here `2020/07/07 09:47:54` from my API in which I'm trying to parse to `2020/07/07 09:47am`. I have tried the following method using intl package but I'm getting an error

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm').add_jm();
DateTime newDate = format.parse(date)
```

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Trying to read   from 2020/07/07 09:47:54 at position 20

Anyone has an idea what seems wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

I found a way in which i need to parse the string date into a DateTime format then reformat it again based on what I needed.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd h:m').parse(date);
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd h:m a');
final String formatted = formatter.format(dateTime);
```

Comment: How you gonna get the AM/PM data with this? may be you need to parse your date with HH:mm in first line

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this line of code:

```
String date = DateFormat.yMEd().add_jms().format(DateTime.now());
String dateWithT = date.substring(0, 8) + 'T' + date.substring(8);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateWithT);
```

Comment: Nope doesn't work I'm getting `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Trying to read EEE from 2020/07/07 09:47:54 at position 0`

Comment: I've edited it, your data is now stored in `dateTime`

Comment: not sure If u realized but my date is from the API not the current date. However I've already found the solution thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatting it twice like this:

```
String date = '2020/07/07 09:47:54';
DateFormat myDateFormat = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm');
DateTime newDate = myDateFormat.parse(date);
var myString = myDateFormat.format(newDate) + DateFormat('a').format(newDate);
```